# How to install Unity desktop on 18.10?

Tags: unity, 18.10

I want to use Unity desktop environment on my modern Ubuntu 18.10 instead of GNOME Shell.

Which package should I install?

Comment: Do you **really** want to do that? Unity is old, outdated, unsupported. GNOME is the modern, current, and supported DE. It almost 99% looks/acts like Unity, with its dock, etc.

Comment: @heynnema GNOME 3 is considerably laggier and slower than Unity. It's also buggy.

Comment: @Riki137 mostly when users install buggy GNOME extensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to search results from [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=unity+desktop&searchon=names) you need to install `ubuntu-unity-desktop` meta-package ("*The Ubuntu Unity desktop system*"):

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Then reconfigure LightDM as main greeter when prompted or manually with

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

And continue to use it as before. Below are a screenshots from 18.10:

[image: LightDM]
[image: Unity]